# How to use Boost and pybind11 on GitHub Actions

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, github-actions, pybind11

I am trying to setup GitHub actions for a code that uses Boost, Eigen, and pybind11. The CMakeLists.txt and the .yml file are below. I am having the following problems: CMake cannot find Boost on the Linux version and on the Windows code only 64 bits Boost is installed. Eigen does not seem to give me any problems and on macOS the code works fine. So I have the following questions:

1. How should I install Boost on GitHub actions? I tried the three options on the .yml file below (using the action commented out in the file, using Conda and using apt-get on Linux). What is the recommended way to install Boost on GitHub actions that works for all operating systems?
2. How do I get CMake to find Boost on Linux? With the exact same code CMake is able to find Boost on macOS and Windows, but not on Linux. I guess I need to set some environment variable, but not sure which and how? Does anyone have a working example of .yml and CMakeLists.txt where CMake could find Boost on Linux?
3. When the action runs on Windows it works fine on Windows 64 bits, but if fails on 32 bits because the Boost installed is 64 bits. How can I install 32 bits Boost when running on Windows 32 bits?

This is the CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(Test)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0054 NEW)

if(MSVC)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /permissive-")
endif()

add_subdirectory(pybind11)

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono thread serialization REQUIRED)

include_directories (
  /usr/local/include
  ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include
  ${USER_INCLUDE_PATH} )

link_directories (
  /usr/local/lib
  ${USER_LIBRARY_PATH} )

pybind11_add_module(_test test.cpp)

target_link_libraries (
  _test PRIVATE
  Boost::chrono
  Boost::thread
  Boost::serialization )
```

and this is the GitHub actions .yml file:

```
name: Build wheels

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  # Build wheels for macOS, Linux, and Windows
  build_wheels:
    name: Wheel for ${{ matrix.os }}-cp${{ matrix.python }}
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [windows-latest, ubuntu-latest, macos-latest]
        python: [36, 37, 38, 39]

    steps:
      # - name: Install boost
      #   uses: MarkusJx/install-boost@v2.0.0
      #   id: install-boost
      #   with:
      #     boost_version: 1.71.0
      #   if: runner.os == 'Windows'

      - name: Set up conda environment
        uses: conda-incubator/setup-miniconda@v2
        with:
          miniconda-version: "latest"
          auto-update-conda: true
          activate-environment: conda-env
        if: runner.os == 'Windows' || runner.os == 'Linux'

      - name: Install libraries for Windows
        run: |
          conda install -c conda-forge boost
          conda install -c conda-forge eigen
        shell: pwsh
        if: runner.os == 'Windows'

      - name: Install libraries for Linux
        run: |
          conda install -c conda-forge boost
          conda install -c conda-forge eigen
          # sudo apt-get update
          # sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
        shell: bash
        if: runner.os == 'Linux'

      - name: Install libraries for macOS
        run: |
          brew upgrade
          brew install boost
          brew install eigen
        shell: bash
        if: runner.os == 'macOS'

      - name: Checkout repository and submodules
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Set up Python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v2

      - name: Install cibuildwheel
        run: python -m pip install cibuildwheel

      - name: Build wheel
        run:
          python -m cibuildwheel --output-dir wheelhouse
        env:
          CIBW_BUILD: cp${{ matrix.python }}-*

      - name: Show files
        run: ls -lh wheelhouse
        shell: bash

      - name: Verify clean directory
        run: git diff --exit-code
        shell: bash

      - name: Upload artifacts
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          path: wheelhouse/*.whl
```

Comment: I should add that with the configurations above (with the CMakeLists.txt file above) the code works fine on a Linux box if Boost is installed. It only fails when running as a GitHub action.

Comment: Do you have issues during the compilation or linking stage?

Comment: During the compilation. CMake says it cannot find Boost during compilation. The problem seems to be with the command `find_package(Boost COMPONENTS chrono thread serialization REQUIRED)`.

Answer (score 0):

I never used GitHub Actions with Windows, but for Linux I had a setup pretty similar to yours, using `apt-get` to install boost. The only difference I can see is that I explicitly told CMake where to look for Boost's includes with

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that `${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}` is empty when running as a GitHub action. I think the problem is that the runner does not set the environment variables correctly. As I added on my comment above, the CMakeLists.txt works fine on a Linux machine.